# Search 'AS' alias in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have a sql query that pulls the customers full name from the customers table based on the customer ID in the sales table and binds the info to an asp.net listview. I now want to search the records by the customers full name. I used the query below but it keeps telling me that the column "Fullname" is an invalid column name. How do I go about modifying this query to work?

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Sales.SaleID, tbl_Sales.CustomerID, 
    (SELECT Firstname + ' ' + Lastname 
     FROM tbl_Customers 
     WHERE CustomerID = tbl_Sales.CustomerID) AS CustomerName, 
    tbl_Sales.Price 
FROM 
    tbl_Sales 
WHERE 
    CustomerName LIKE '%John%'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

Comment: Thanks @juergend that makes perfect sense when I think about it now. I just assumed it would have a value based on the order it was executed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `Alias name` in the same select statement because `where` will be processed before the `select`.

Make the original query as `sub select` and use the `alias name` in `where clause`.Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT tbl_Sales.SaleID,
               tbl_Sales.CustomerID,
               (SELECT Firstname + ' ' + Lastname
                FROM   tbl_Customers
                WHERE  CustomerID = tbl_Sales.CustomerID) AS CustomerName,
               tbl_Sales.Price
        FROM   tbl_Sales) A
WHERE  CustomerName LIKE '%John%'
```

or use `Cross apply`

```
SELECT tbl_Sales.SaleID,
       tbl_Sales.CustomerID,
       t.CustomerName,
       tbl_Sales.Price
FROM   tbl_Sales
       CROSS apply (SELECT Firstname + ' ' + Lastname AS CustomerName
                    FROM   tbl_Customers
                    WHERE  CustomerID = tbl_Sales.CustomerID) t
WHERE  t.CustomerName LIKE '%John%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to pass **ALIAS name** in **WHERE** clause instead of that you should use **JOIN**

Try this:

```
SELECT S.SaleID, S.CustomerID, (C.Firstname + ' ' + C.Lastname) AS CustomerName, S.Price 
FROM tbl_Sales S
INNER JOIN tbl_Customers C ON S.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
WHERE (C.Firstname + ' ' + C.Lastname) LIKE '%John%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the combined value, you could check each column like this. Combining the columns and comparing is not [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), and will result in bad performance:

```
SELECT 
  tbl_Sales.SaleID,
  tbl_Sales.CustomerID,
  cus.Firstname + ' ' + cus.Lastname CustomerName, 
   tbl_Sales.Price 
FROM
  tbl_Sales 
JOIN
  tbl_Customers cus
ON
  cus.CustomerID = tbl_Sales.CustomerID
WHERE
  (cus.Firstname LIKE '%John%' or
  cus.Lastname LIKE '%John%')
```